# Monitoring UI when Hangfire server part of seperate process?

Tags: hangfire

Where or how would one get to the Hangfire monitoring UI dashboard if you were to install Hangfire nuget packages as part of a seperate (windows) service?

eg. this 
[image]

instead of this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the diagram in your question, the bridge between a Hangfire Dashboard and Hangfire background workers is the **storage** that they share... The Dashboard displays information about the jobs, based on what it sees in the storage, and the background workers execute and report on jobs by reading/writing from/to the storage.

e.g. If you're using, SQL Server as the storage, then you can have a Dashboard hosted in one web app, and one or more background workers hosted in Windows Service(s), as long as you **have them all point to the same SQL Server database**.

Hangfire's documentation is pretty straightforward and describes:

- [How to set up a stand-alone Dashboard](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-dashboard.html#adding-dashboard)
- [How to process jobs in a Windows Service](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/processing-jobs-in-windows-service.html)

---

If it helps, in the repository of [Hangfire.Dashboard.Customize](https://github.com/caioproiete/hangfire-dashboard-customize) you can see examples of a standalone Hangfire Dashboard being hosted inside:

- [An ASP .NET Core application](https://github.com/caioproiete/hangfire-dashboard-customize/tree/master/sample/)
- [A Console application (Owin-based)](https://github.com/caioproiete/hangfire-dashboard-customize/tree/master/sample/)